# how I can prevent CreateView ( django 1.6) redirect me to the success_url if the form is valid and so just return a json?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I try overriding the form_valid method returning the json instead of HttpResponseRedirect, but that does not work. Just raise me this error: `"The view did not return an HttpResponse object."`

this is the code of my view:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import TestForm
import json,urllib2

class CreateViewTest(CreateView):
    form_class=TestForm
    template_name="Test.html"
    success_url = ""

    def form_valid(self, form):
        urllib2.urlopen('returnjson/',json.dumps(form.data))
        #returning here try different things but all gave me the same error
```

Comment: that's  the code of my view. .

Answer (score 4):

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def form_valid(self, form):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(form.data), content_type='application/json')
```

Alternatively, for the sake of reusability I'd recommend you to create a `mixin` instead responsible for rendering a JSON response only when request is *AJAX*:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class JsonResponseFormMixin(FormMixin):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(form.data), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            return super(JsonResponseFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return return HttpResponse(json.dumps(form.errors), content_type='application/json', status_code=400)
        else:
            return super(JsonResponseFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)


from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import TestForm

class CreateViewTest(CreateView, JsonResponseFormMixin):
    form_class = TestForm
```

Comment: What does return return mean?